# Higher Order Component not firing wrapper render in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a high order component that is not rendering the child on a render change.  The code below has been chopped down for simplicity sake.

The HOC that looks like this:

```
const withMyComponent = (WrapperComponent) => {
    class HOC extends Component {
        state = {
            value: ''
        };

        changedHandler = (event) => {
            this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
        };

        render() {
            return (<WrapperComponent {...this.props}
                changed={this.changedHandler}
                value={this.state.value} />);
        }
    };

    return HOC;
};

export default withMyComponent;
```

Then I have a child component that uses this HOC:

```
class myChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text"
                onChange={(event) => this.props.changed(event)}
                value={this.props.value || ''} />
        );
    };
};

export default withMyComponent(myChildComponent);
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the `input` is not updating with the new value that is passed back from the HOC.  In fact, the child render is not even firing after the initial mount and doesn't seem to fire on any changed event.

I have placed debugging and `console.logs` in the HOC render and the changed event and the render are firing with the proper data.

So, if I type in the textbox, it fires the change event in the HOC and updates the state in the HOC and fires the render event in the HOC.  But it is not firing the wrapped components render event, and thus the textbox never updates with any values.

Anyone able to solve this issue or lead me in the right direction?

Thanks again.

Comment: Aside from the `this.setState(value: event.target.value)` typo (argument should be an object), your example works fine for me

Comment: After making the change, it still not working for me. :(

Comment: This issue was resolved.  It was due to order of multiple HOCs (not shown in example) being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an object to `this.setState`

```js
const withMyComponent = WrapperComponent => {
  class HOC extends Component {
    state = {
      value: ""
    };

    changedHandler = event => {
      // Instead of 
      // this.setState( value: event.target.value );

      // Do This.
      this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    };

    render() { ... }
  }

  return HOC;
};
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit zq6vk36z3m]

Comment: This issue was resolved.  It was due to order of multiple HOCs (not shown in example) being used.